# Grizzly FilterChain vs. HttpHandler

Tags: grizzly

I am trying to learn Grizzly. My background is in .NET. When I read through Grizzly's tutorials, a few things confused me.

My confusion is related to the basic difference between `HttpHandler` and `FilterChain`. What I understood is that we can create custom filters which can act upon requests and then invoke the next item in a filter chain.

Is a filter chain kind of a pipeline for processing incoming requests? HTTP handlers do the same thing, but only for HTTP requests, right? What is the basic difference between the two, and where do they fit together?

It would be helpful to have a diagram which shows the network listener, filter chain and HTTP handler all fitting together and processing requests.

Answer (score 1):

`Filter` and `FilterChain` are the core abstractions in the Grizzly framework. They are used to implement any protocol, and HTTP is one of them.

`HttpServer` and `HttpHandler` are higher-level abstractions. They provide a Servlet-like API to work with HTTP requests. The `HttpServer`, under the hood, is built on top of `FilterChain`. `Filter`s and `HttpHandler` represent a piece of logic that processes HTTP requests sent for the specific URL, which you set when registering an `HttpHandler` on an `HttpServer`.

Coming back to the `HttpServer` vs. `FilterChain` question, here is an example of how `HttpServer`'s `FilterChain` looks:

- HTTP protocol:  TransportFilter <-> HttpCodecFilter <-> HttpServerFilter
- HTTPS protocol: TransportFilter <-> SslFilter <-> HttpCodecFilter <-> HttpServerFilter

Did that help?